# Automated Rules Discount

Tags: 7, ubercart

I have installed 'Ubercart Discount Coupons' module and managed to add a rule to configure the automated discount. But now all the normal code type discounts have stopped working....

Only when I remove the automated discount rule the normal code discounts will works.

I am struck on the production site.

Screenshots:

[image]

Comment: If you don't have any custom on that rule, you can revert it to default value. Did you try that?

Comment: Sorry.. I did not get you.. what is custom on rules? please explain it to me.

Comment: In other words, do you want to have a general automated discount that applies to all transactions AND specific discounts that are applied with coupon codes? If so, have you looked at the order your rules are applied?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to configure one automated discount and normal code based discounts.

Comment: Currently the problem is when I add a rule for automated discount, the normal code based discounts stops working.

Comment: And the discount will be applied to products of one particular taxonomy term automatically, and other products will have product specific code based discount

Comment: Can you either supply a screengrab of your rules or show an example of the product price and discounts structure you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi Longboardnode, I have updated the screenshots above. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I figured out the problem.

This Issue was in the 'Coupon module settings'.

Solution:
1. Go to: admin/store/settings/coupon
2. Enable 'Allow multiple coupons to apply to a single order.' check-box.
3. Save.

This solved my problem.

Thanks,
Anand

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer of AnAnD worked for me as well.

As of 2018 (Drupal 7.59, Ubercart 3.11) I found the setting under `Administration > Store > Configuration > Coupon module settings`.